# Incorrect behavior with CMake-generated DLL and Curiously Recurring Templates (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, cmake

I've run into a confusing problem with CMake-generated DLL files on Windows.  In my library, I use Curiously Recurring Template Pattern to give a certain classes a unique ID number:

```
// da/Attribute.h:

#ifndef DA_ATTRIBUTE_H
#define DA_ATTRIBUTE_H

namespace da {

typedef unsigned int AttributeId;

class AttributeBase {
public:
    virtual AttributeId getTypeId() const=0;

protected:
    /** Static ID counter.  Every class that derives da::AttributeBase is
        assigned an increment of this counter as its type ID number */
    static AttributeId sNextId;

};

template <class Derived>
class Attribute : public AttributeBase {
private:
    static AttributeId msTypeId;

public:
    Attribute() {
        if (msTypeId == 0) {
            msTypeId = ++sNextId;
        }
    }

    virtual ~Attribute() {

    }

    /** For static contexts */
    static AttributeId typeId() {
        if (msTypeId == 0) {
            msTypeId = ++sNextId;
        }

        return msTypeId;
    }

    AttributeId getTypeId() const {
        return typeId();
    }

};

template <class Derived> AttributeId Attribute<Derived>::msTypeId = 0;

}

#endif
```

Problem is, when I link the DLL to an executable project, there appears to be some inconsistencies with the different ID methods.  For example:

```
// Foo.h
struct Foo : public da::Attribute<Foo> {
    Foo() { }
};
```

...

```
// main.cpp
Foo *foo = new Foo;    

Foo->getTypeId() == 1 // True
Foo::typeId() == 1 // Should be true, but isn't.  Foo::typeId() == 2
```

Running through with GDB, with a break in Foo::getTypeID(), **I found that "msTypeId" and "Foo::msTypeId" had different memory addresses.**  What the hell.

This only happens when Foo is defined in the DLL, though.  (And only in Windows 7, apparently--I don't have this problem in my Debian build)  If I create the derived class inside main.cpp, or if I just compile all the code from the library into the executable, skipping the DLL step entirely, it works with no problems.

Everything was compiled using MSYS and MinGW, with GCC 4.7 on Windows 7 Home Premium.

Here's the CMakeLists.txt for the library, in case I messed something up there:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(foo)

add_definitions(-std=c++0x)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

set(sources
    Foo.cpp
)

add_library(foo SHARED ${sources})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to export the types from the shared library. This is done using the [`__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx) decorators. Read through the MSDN documentation; it's rather involved.

Since the header needs to have `__declspec(dllexport)` when building the library and `__declspec(dllimport)` when compiling the code that uses it, one usually defines a symbol, customarily called `LIBRARYNAME_EXPORT` and #ifdefs it depending on whether `LIBRARYNAME_EXPORTS` is defined.

CMake automatically defines `target_EXPORTS` when building (shared) library. It can be overridden by setting `DEFINE_SYMBOL` target property.

Unix chooses a different path and by default exports and also imports all symbols from shared libraries (except for static and explicitly hidden ones). This incurs a little bit of performance penalty as more symbols need to be resolved, but it much easier to use (no changes are needed to switch from static to shared library) and much more flexible (i.e. you can override symbols from shared libraries, which you can't do in Windows).